# Express the determinant of the transformation $Φ : L(V, W) \to L(V, W)$, $Φ(\psi) = \psi \circ \phi$ by $\dim(V )$, $\dim(W )$ and $\det(\phi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

There are linear spaces $V$, $W$ over a field $K$: $\dim(V ) = n$, $\dim(W) = m$ and there is a linear transformation $Φ : V \to V$. We define the function $Φ : L(V, W) \to L(V, W)$ by the formula: $Φ(\psi) = \psi \circ \phi$.

Express the determinant of the transformation Φ by $m$, $n$ and $\det(\phi)$.

---

I know that I can express transformation $Φ$ as a matrix:
$$\mathcal{M}(Φ(\psi))^{St}_{St} = \mathcal{M}(\psi \circ \phi)^{St}_{St} = \mathcal{M}(\psi)^{St}_{St} \cdot \mathcal{M}(\phi)^{St}_{St}$$

And then:

$$\det \left| \mathcal{M}(Φ(\psi))^{St}_{St} \right| = \det \left| \mathcal{M}(\psi)^{St}_{St} \right| \cdot \det \left| \mathcal{M}(\phi)^{St}_{St} \right| \to \det \left| \mathcal{M}(Φ(\psi))^{St}_{St} \right| = \det \left| \mathcal{M}(\psi)^{St}_{St} \right| \cdot \det(\phi) $$

Now I need to express $\det \left| \mathcal{M}(\psi)^{St}_{St} \right|$ with $m$, $n$ and $\det(\phi)$ and I don't know how to do that part.

Comment: Pick a basis of $W$. You'll find that $\Phi$ amounts to a direct sum of $\dim W$ copies of (the dual of) $\phi$ and you can determine its determinant from there.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? Is that equivalent to $F^{*}(\phi) = \phi \circ F$ (I found that on the Internet). How do I find out that from basis of $W$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $F$ there. First see if you can understand the special case that $W$ is the ground field $K$. Then try to understand $W = K \oplus K$.

Comment: I mean conjugate space of some matrix F (agin, I found it n the Internet and don't even know if that is true). Maybe let's start from the very beginning - what does it mean that function is $L(V, W) \to L(V, W)$? Normally I would think that it takes values from <left of arrow> and returns values <right of arrow >, but here are two spaces in the braces and I don't know why. The function is later defined by a formula with just one value that is being taken. How can 1 value come from 2 spaces? Or how do I understand that  definition of the function?

Comment: Okay, if you don't even know what some notation in the question means that really should've been your first question. (How can you expect to solve a question without knowing what it says?) $L(V, W)$ is the space of linear maps $V \to W$. It is itself a vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, of dimension $(\dim V)(\dim W)$. If you pick bases of $V, W$ it can be identified with the vector space of matrices (of the appropriate dimensions). $\Phi$ is an operator on this vector space, meaning it takes as input a linear map and returns as output another linear map.

Comment: A warm-up exercise before trying to tackle this one is to get any sense at all of what $\Phi$ is even doing. Take $V = W = K^2$ so that $L(V, W)$ can be identified with the $2 \times 2$ matrices $M_2(K)$ and $\phi : K^2 \to K^2$ can be identified with a particular matrix $M$. Then try to compute the action of $M$ by right multiplication on the $2 \times 2$ matrices. To be really explicit, try writing down a basis of the $2 \times 2$ matrices and compute the matrix of right multiplication by $M$ with respect to this basis, which will be a $4 \times 4$ matrix.